# Can't publish markdown to Rpub on Windows

Tags: r, ssl, rstudio

After compile the R Markdown document with knitr package in html file, I tried to push to RPub with the "Publish" bottom. However, I am getting error as:

"Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
Calls: rpubsUpload ...  -> .postForm -> .Call ->  -> fun
Execution halted"

I am using windows RStudio Version 0.98.1091.I am assuming it is because windows to Rpub connection configuration issue.

First time using the Rpub. Could you help where to config the SSL certificate on windows? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Under preferences in Rstudio, there is a tab "git/SVN".

Have you created an "RSA" key?

This can be done through github.

See https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/