# R Markdown RPubs error

Tags: r, publish

I followed the steps outlined in https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/01/29/rstudio-r-markdown-r-scripts-rpubs/
but encounter error as in [Can't publish markdown to Rpub on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466382/cant-publish-markdown-to-rpub-on-windows/28059923#28059923)

Step 1:

> install.packages('knitr', dependencies = TRUE)

Step 2:

> library('knitr')

Step 3:
File-> New File-> R Markdown. 
Key in Title, Author, and choose HTML radio button.
Some template appear..

Step 4:
Click knit HTML button

Step 5: 
I create a free account by visiting www.rpubs.com.

Step 5: 
Click Publish.
Once you click the publish button you will be prompted to login with your RPubs account. --> I do not have this...

But I have error:
"Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate Calls: rpubsUpload ... -> .postForm -> .Call -> -> fun Execution halted"

Answer (score 1):

Boniface Osonwanne's answer at https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202496207-Difficulties-in-publishing-R-presentation-in-RPubs worked for me with a little tweaking.

To summarize, he said open up the following directory:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\library\base\R
```

Then add the following line using Notepad on line 25.

```
options(rpubs.upload.method = "internal")
```

Notepad made a mess of the file for me, but Notepad++ worked fine.

My problem came in when I tried to save. Even though I had just rebooted and didn't have R or Rstudio open, I couldn't save. I copied the file to my desktop made the edit there and copied the file back with administrator permissions.

When I started R and knitted my Rmd, it worked like a charm.